# Finding Covariance of returns of a portfolio

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, covariance, portfolio

I have created a portfolio of 5 stocks and I want to find the annual returns and volatility of the entire portfolio. Here is my code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:\stock_1.csv")

df2 = pd.read_csv("C:\stock_2.csv")

df3 = pd.read_csv("C:\stock_3.csv")

df4 = pd.read_csv("C:\stock_4.csv")

df5 = pd.read_csv("C:\stock_5.csv")

frames = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5]
data = pd.concat(frames,axis=0)
print(data)

data.to_csv("C:\final.csv")
data_new = data['Close Price']
data_new.sort_index(inplace=True)

returns = data_new.pct_change()

mean_daily_returns = returns.mean()
cov_matrix = returns.cov()

weights = np.asarray([0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2])

portfolio_return = round(np.sum(mean_daily_returns * weights) * 252,2)

portfolio_std_dev = round(np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252),2)
print(portfolio_return)
print(portfolio_std_dev)
```

I am getting the error as:

```
cov_matrix = returns.cov()
TypeError: cov() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
```

Comment: My DataFrame structure was wrong. I modified the DataFrame showing date wise Closing Price against each stock (Stocks are in column). That solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: oh yes sure, sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1):

In this line of code:

```
cov_matrix = returns.cov()
```

you want to compute the covariance of a `pandas.Series`. According to pandas [documentation](http://cov_matrix%20=%20returns.cov()), you need to specify the `other` parameter with which to compute the covariance. Basically you need an other Series with which to compare `'Close Price'`.